# Best JQuery grids compatible with SharePoint Web Part with excel like features and column validations

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2013

i wanted to implement the grid in one of my SharePoint visual web part with basic grid functionalities like grouping, sorting, column freezing(fixed left columns),column data validation, setting column/row read only, customizable grid cells,excel features like copy,paste.
can someone suggest a Jquery grid or any other grid with above mentioned functionalities which i can include in my SharePoint visual Web part.

Answer (score 0):

Use JQuery DataTable Grid

It is simple jquery plugin which uses datatable as its datasource and can be implemented in one line only.

You can refer to:

Official site [Data Table](http://datatables.net/),this grid is responsive with various features like client side searching, sorting, paging etc.Its functionality can be enhanced by using various plugins given in site and is easy to implement.

Use this reference to implement above grid on web part in sharepoint [link.](http://www.ashokraja.me/post/jQuery-Data-Tables-Web-Part-in-SharePoint-2013.aspx)

Hope this help.

Answer (score -1):

Look for the Kendo UI Grids. But they are not free

Comment: i'm looking for something which is opensource

Comment: You have not specified about the free or paid version so it is not acceptable to have the answer negative marking

Answer (score -1):

You can use jQGrid. It is free and has a lot of features. http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html